# state redirect with object as parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm looking for a way to redirect between states and give an object as parameter. I considered using stateParam but the parameter is way to long and complex to do so.

My first option is to use the `rootScope` as a transaction medium and use `state.go()` to redirect but I'm wondering if there is an other way to do so.

Comment: Why don't you give an Id as parameter then with that Id you call a function to take your object ? Edit:  Yes i think use $rootScope can be a good way.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll implement it this way

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is possible using just `ui-router`. Have a look on [how to pass parameters without specifying them in the state URLs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls). You'll see that things are straightforward and you don't need to create additional services or attach the data to `$rootScope`.

Here's a working example:

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('stateA', {
          url: '/stateA',
          params: {
            paramAsObject: null
          },

          controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams',
            function($scope, $stateParams) {
              $scope.myObject = {
                name: 'myName',
                nested: {
                  name: 'I am nested',
                  numeric: 123
                }
              };

              console.log($stateParams);
            }
          ],
          template: '<div><h1>Hello from stateA</h1><p>Check the console logs! <a ui-sref="stateB({paramAsObject:myObject})">Go to stateB</a></p></div>'
        })
        .state('stateB', {
          url: '/stateB',
          params: {
            paramAsObject: null
          },

          controller: ['$stateParams',
            function($stateParams) {
              console.log($stateParams);
            }
          ],
          template: '<div><h1>Hello from stateB</h1><p>Check the console logs!</p></div>'
        });

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/stateA');
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```